# Intento Ingresar una Imagen bitmap a un Linearlayout en Android

Tags: android, bitmap, linearlayout

Intento que mi linearlayout tenga un fondo con una imagen bitmap

```
Bitmap ImagenProducto = list.get(position).getImagenProducto();
holder.LinearlayoutImage.setImageBitmap(ImagenProducto);
```

Comment: ¿Y el problema es?

Comment: el linearlayout no permite un bitmap ni en el background el elemento no es una imageview

Comment: Entiendo, entonces tu problema es que no puedes insertar una imagen con formato bmp ya que en los background solo se permiten png, jpg, etc ¿Verdad? La solución es que puedes parsear la imagen bmp o convertirla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si hay solucion pero de diferente manera hay que tener en cuenta que lo que yo obtengo es un string del bitmap de la imagen.

```
Bitmap ImagenProducto = list.get(position).getImagenProducto();
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), ImagenProducto);
holder.LinearlayoutImage.setBackground(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
Bitmap ImagenProducto = list.get(position).getImagenProducto();
ImagenProducto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, dondeSeGuardará);
holder.LinearlayoutImage.setBackground(ImagenProducto);
```

Comment: recuerde que el linearlayout no acepta setImageBitmap y ademas noo me conviene guardar una gran cantidad de imagenes en mi aplicacion si recibo una lista muy grande de imagenes Arriba mostre la captura del codigo, necesito saber comohacer que el linearlayout acepte un background con un bitmap

Comment: Disculpa, me olvidé de corregir eso. Es un `setBackground`

Answer (score 0):

[image: el problema del linearlayout con una imagen bitmap]

un linearlayout no acepta imagenes bitmap, yo recibo una lista de imagenes code64 como string y las convierto en bitmap para mostrarlas en imageview con el setImageBitmap pero el LinearLayout no me permite usar el setImageBitmap.

Comment: Por que es un linear layout y no una imageview.  Cada uno hace cosas diferentes, Aqui toda la informacion  -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear?hl=es-419